# How do I bypass this Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day, i have a shuffling script that works on radio buttons on a page, it uses Jquery, my problem is after i had included jquery, and the script follows under with its call, i get an error (from google chrome developer console)

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shuffle is not a function
```

i've tried getting my head round this but i'm stuck. Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
   $.fn.shuffle = function() {
    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
       });

    this.each(function(i){
        $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });

    return $(shuffled);

    }; 
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The call of the script/function

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.questions label').shuffle();
  });
 </script>
```

the HTML

```
<div class="questions">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="Hello">Hello
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="Hello">Hello1<br>
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="Hello">Hello2
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="choices" value="Hello">Hello3
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ondra Zizka thanks for the edit

Comment: @Santi since its an outdated one can you refer a current version of it

Comment: Where did you get that? It looks like a fairly poor way to suffle DOM elements. For one thing, it clones them for no apparent reason.

Comment: Looks like your trying to extend jquery....see if this helps:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: @JaredSmith where can i get it please and which part of my script should i include it?

Comment: Works as expected? https://jsfiddle.net/v18jhbf4/

Comment: The error doesn't happen if I put that code in a fiddle (without the surprising default): https://jsfiddle.net/fvukt597/

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/wuligo/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  it works but why not in my local script

Comment: Where is that second code block located with respect to the first code block?  Is it above it or below it?

Answer (score 0):

guys i got a solution for it 
after serious brainstorming

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    var choices = $("#choices");

    choices.html(
        choices.find("label").sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
        })
    );    
});
</script>
```